# No items when using Earl RSS Reader Android

Tags: android, rss

So I'm using Earl RSS library for parsing RSS on Android. It retrieves the link fine and it reads the title of the feed and everything. The only problem is when I get getItems() it always return 0.

```
url = new URL("http://techcrunch.com/feed/?format=xml");
        feedInputStream = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
        Feed feed = EarlParser.parseOrThrow(feedInputStream, 5);
        Log.e("FeedAdapter", "feed title : " + feed.getTitle());

        for (Item item : feed.getItems())
            Log.e("FeedAdapter", " post title : " + item.getTitle());
```

That outputs:

```
E/FeedAdapter: feed title : TechCrunch
```

And nothing for the second Log because getItems() is 0

Comment: Have you tried using any other feeds? Perhaps there's something about TechCrunch's that is confusing this parser. Or, file an issue with the project. You might need to consider [alternative libraries](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/86).

Comment: Yeah it seems it's just TechCrunch. I've tried it on other feeds and it works fine